# Template matching - drawing shape on matching on GUI

Tags: python, image, function, user-interface, image-processing

I'm working on template matching 
Using implemented function to make a match space between them and getting local maxima of the expected matches in the original photo

now, I have the local maxima points  x , y  displayed in a list

in my GUI I want to draw a rectangle or a circle around the point of local maxima
displaying them in the detected pattern label (grayscale of original image with the rectangle on the detected shape)
like this

[GUI Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JNPZN.png)

two functions for rectangle and circle, how can i connect those two functions to be drawn around the point of local maxima when i already display an image on the label in the GUI, such that the local maxima point is taken and used to be the center of the rectangle on the displayed image on label
except those functions are with matplot i want them on already existing image on label in GUI

```
def make_rects(plt_object,xy,template):
        htemp, wtemp = template.shape
        for ridx in range(xy.shape[0]):
            y,x = xy[ridx]
            r =  plt.Rectangle((x-wtemp/2, y-htemp/2), wtemp, htemp, edgecolor='g', facecolor='none')
            plt_object.add_patch(r)

    def make_circles(plt_object,xy,template):
        htemp, wtemp = template.shape
        for ridx in range(xy.shape[0]):
            y,x = xy[ridx]
            plt_object.plot(x, y, 'o', markeredgecolor='g', markerfacecolor='none', markersize=10)
```

Here is my implemented function

```
 import numpy as np
 from scipy.signal import correlate2d

        def match_template_corr(x, temp):
            y = np.empty(x.shape)
            y = correlate2d(x, temp, 'same')
            return y
```

GUI Picture:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OpenCV performance on template matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7139606/opencv-performance-on-template-matching)

Comment: This is a pretty common task and there are hundreds of examples to be found. What makes your case special?

Comment: That i'm connectiong it with GUI and I'm not using a built-in function

Comment: my problem is drawing circles or rectangles around the point of maxima

Comment: Everybody is doing that https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_template_matching/py_template_matching.html

Comment: https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/finding-waldo-feature-matching-for-opencv-9bded7f5ab10

Comment: http://cs231n.stanford.edu/reports/2017/pdfs/817.pdf

Comment: Try to break you problem down into simple parts: 1.) show images in a GUI 2.) use a template matching algorithm 3.) drawing circles and rectangles in your GUI. Solve each of this, then combine them.

Comment: they use matchTemplate from openCv , they are using matplot , I'm using implemented function and i should display the image on a label on GUI

Comment: Your "implemented function" is something that you find as very simple example in the documentation to [scipy.signal.correlate2d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.signal.correlate2d.html). The line `y = np.empty(x.shape)` does not do anything. Ok, then from the list I mentioned above, you did 2.), now do the other parts. Google them separately and you will find plenty examples for your GUI toolkit. Then combine the three things.

Comment: is there any useful link for how to draw a shape on an image on the label in the GUI

Comment: https://github.com/sbme-tutorials/sbme-tutorials.github.io/blob/master/2020/cv/notebooks/template_matching.ipynb , this link works with it , but with plotting not GUI

Comment: which GUI toolkit are you using? Qt, wx, GTK, SWT? You can find a useful link by googling "your toolkit name draw circle"